# Randomly Picking Up An Object In The Array List

Tags: c#

Can i use the random class to retrieve an object randomly from an array list and i know i can't store this randomly retrieved object in variable

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections;

namespace ThreadSample
{

    class FunWithVehicles
    {
           public void VehicleThread1()
           {
                  Console.WriteLine("Type Of Vehicle Is Car\nRegisteration Number Is: TN0098 1234\nLicense Number Is APK32456\nVehicle Number Is 1"); 

           }
           public void VehicleThread2()
           {
                  Console.WriteLine("Type Of Vehicle Is Van\nRegisteration Number Is: TN0012 2385\nLicense Number Is UKL37899\nVehicle Number Is 2");    
           }
           public void VehicleThread3()
           {
                 Console.WriteLine("Type Of Vehicle Is Truck\nRegisteration Number Is: TN1798 8907\nLicense Number Is MNT59863\nVehicle Number Is 3");    
           }
           public void VehicleThread4()
           {
                 Console.WriteLine("Type Of Vehicle Is Tanker\nRegisteration Number Is: TN3987 5357\nLicense Number Is RTJ23498\nVehicle Number Is 4"); 
           }
           public void VehicleThread5()
           {
                 Console.WriteLine("Type Of Vehicle Is Bus\nRegisteration Number Is: TN9768 3212\nLicense Number Is RTJ98734\nVehicle Number Is 5"); 
           }
     }
     class TollGate
     {
            \\ retrieving the randomly stored object happens here and it will check a parameter
            \\ The Parameter Function is to check whether the sent object was already sent and to see whether the previous number is remaining since all the threads have to be sent sequentially
     }
     class Simulate
     {
            public static void Main()
            {
                  Simulate s = new Simulate();
                  Simulate n = new Simulate();
                  FunWithVehicles f = new FunWithVehicles();
                  ThreadStart Ref1 = new ThreadStart(f.VehicleThread1);
                  ThreadStart Ref2 = new ThreadStart(f.VehicleThread2);
                  ThreadStart Ref3 = new ThreadStart(f.VehicleThread3);
                  ThreadStart Ref4 = new ThreadStart(f.VehicleThread4);
                  ThreadStart Ref5 = new ThreadStart(f.VehicleThread5);                     
                  Thread Th1 = new Thread(Ref1);
                  Thread Th2 = new Thread(Ref2);
                  Thread Th3 = new Thread(Ref3);
                  Thread Th4 = new Thread(Ref4);
                  Thread Th5 = new Thread(Ref5);
                  ArrayList items = new ArrayList();
                  items.Add(Th1);
                  items.Add(Th2);
                  items.Add(Th3);
                  items.Add(Th4);
                  items.Add(Th5);
                  Random rnd = new Random();
                  int r = rnd.Next(items.Count);
                  // storing will happen here and it will be sent to the TollGate class to check the parameter
                 // If there are no previous numbers and if is not sent, it will be processed  and displayed  in the TollGate class and decremented from the array list right here in the simulate class, so the next time only 4 objects will be remaining and once all the threads are processed the application stops 

            }
      }
```

I want to randomly pick an object and store it so that it can be sent to another class. I don't know what exactly to put in the The Parameter Function to make it work and how to make the decrements part of it work.
Any help would be appreciated.For the display i got Thread.Start(); but how to fuse it in the existing code to make it work. How to Number the threads or function so that it knows about processing the threads sequentially.

Comment: Did you know that the  ArrayList class is obsolete? Use List instead.

Comment: That's what is given as my assignment.

Comment: In this case, they are teaching you to use an obsolete type that shouldn't have been used since .NET 2.0 - about 8 years ago. You need to find a better school.

Answer (score 2):

Why not.

Use `Random` class `Next(int minvalue, int maxvalue)` method to give value less than the length of the array list.

Then use that random value as index to get value from array list.

This way

```
ArrayList ar = new ArrayList();

//Fill Array List

Random r = new Random();

int rand = r.Next(0, ar.Count);

var value = ar[rand];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Random you already have, and do this.

```
 object picked = items[rnd.Next(0,items.Count)];
```